# Does Julia push! require a copy of the entire array

Tags: julia

Looking into the code of push!,  indicates that the array is grown the size of one element. Does the array logically grow the size of one element while the underlying storage stays the same as long as it is greater or equal than the required stored elements, and grown by creating a significantly larger storage and copying the entire array into it when the storage being full cannot accommodate the extra element? Or alternatively, does the array have to be recreated upon each push! operation.

```
function push!(a::Array{T,1}, item) where T
    # convert first so we don't grow the array if the assignment won't work
    itemT = convert(T, item)
    _growend!(a, 1)
    a[end] = itemT
    return a
end
```

Comment: As stated in the answer, arrays are currently have growth factor of 2, so you only need log2(N) reallocations (or copies) to grow N elements. Also, if you have a rough idea how much space you need up-front you can use the `sizehint!` function to minimise reallocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia arrays grow in such a way that the cost is amortized (currently with a growth factor of 2), see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost.

Comment: Doing some benchmarks seem to confirm this in terms of performance. That said, could you provide a reference? This brings up another question: Such mechanism obviously requires bound checks that affects performance when compared with plain C arrays. What do you think?

Comment: start with https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/array.jl#L910 and then go down the called functions up to C implementation that you have here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/6d49bc91a29d69d1fccf85f8738c919ca2339367/src/array.c#L875.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Fair enough. Will do :-)

Comment: > This brings up another question: Such mechanism obviously requires bound checks that affects performance when compared with plain C arrays.

What do yo mean here? C arrays are not growable so you must mean something different than that.